# Error while compiling a library with mex - __int 64 does not name a type

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to compile a library using mex in Matlab. I was able to partially compile the thing, but on the last file mex gives an error concerning the two lines:

```
typedef __int64 LONG64; 
typedef __int64 long64;
```

The error says:

> `__int64` does not name a type  `typedef __int64 LONG64;`

Is this just a matter of the C++ code? I'm not at all familiarized with this language and I don't know from where the error comes. Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__int64` is a synonyms that only works for Microsoft Visual C++ 32-bit and 64-bit compilers.

You can use `long long` instead of `__int64`

```
typedef long long LONG64; 
typedef long long long64;
```

Or use `cstdint`:

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef int64_t LONG64; 
typedef int64_t long64;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this, and the error changes into a very long one... Apparently there are some functions in the library which don't like the new type definition.

Comment: Or switch over to `cstdint`'s `int64_t`.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks! Addedd to the body

Comment: Ok, apparently, it works if I run mex directly outside Matlab... Thanks.

Comment: @BeniBogosel "directly outside Matlab" hints that Matlab may have been playing games with the path or the default includes. You used to have to run a command to configure what compiler Matlab was using and where it was located. Can't remember for the life of me what the command is, though.

Comment: Yes, the command is mex -setup. However, I'm not sure why it works one way and not the other... Mex was always a pain for me in Matlab. Best libraries come with precompiled mex files :)